# Ubuntu won't boot AMD FX 6100 & ASUS Radeon 6670

Tags: 12.04

After I install Ubuntu 12.04 and reset I get the Ubuntu loading screen which is offset and then the desktop appears without any icons and still offset.  I can't do anything from this point except turn off the machine or reset.  I am installing on a blank machine with no other OS installed.

ASUS M5A99X EVO Motherboard
AMD FX 6100 Processor
ASUS Radeon HD 6670
8 GB RAM

Comment: Have another Graphics card? I have a Intel I3 and a Radeon HD 6670 and I the same problem. I does work when I use the on-board video. I believe Ubuntu dislikes the Radeon

Answer (score 0):

I would boot with the recovery mode and try to recover broken packages or even update software, for this I have to previously select to connect to the Network.

Otherwise, maybe first if I suppose that I have a good Video driver, I would type from the keyboard Control+Alt+t and then from the Terminal I would type

```
me@ubuntu:~$ gnome-session-save --logout
```